# Firebase Re-use Mail after deleting account fails

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

When deleting an account and trying to create a new one, by first checking if the mail exists, I get the following error:

> Host platform returned null value for non-null return value.

This is how I check if the Mail is already in use, and that function throws the `FirebaseExeption`:

```
 static Future<bool> checkIfEmailIsAlreadyInUse({
    required String email,
  }) async {
    try {
      final list = await _firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(
        email,
      );
      if (list.isNotEmpty) {
        // Return true because there is an existing
        // user using the email address
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      AlertService.showSnackBar(
        title: 'Hopla, hier ist etwas schiefgelaufen...',
        description: e.message ?? 'Unbekannter Fehler',
        isSuccess: false,
      );
      return true;
    }
  }
```

When trying to login with the Mail, I get the following message:

> There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may
> have been deleted.

Is it not possible to re-use a mail after deleting it? I checked my database, and everything is deleted correctly.